# Addition of rows - grid Tkinter. Individual commands for OptionMenu

Tags: python, class, lambda, tkinter, ttk

I have created a table in Tkinter by repetition of widgets following the importation of a text file (which therefore creates new rows depending on the containing information).

The following image shows that I need to be able to create from column '7' onwards a separate area of entry boxes depending on the OptionMenu choice.

[image: Table]

For an option list the user is asked how many entry boxes they wish to fill in (therefore 'n' boxes created). For a 'Fixed' value there should be no boxes and any before deleted. For two other options in the OptionMenu there is always a Min and Max value (2 boxes). Each value in these boxes needs to be collected following their input via the user.

I have previously had help with the possibility of create a new frame each time but if possible would like to use the same one. I have the following code for the choice:

```
if choice == "Fixed":

    for i in xrange(self.number_boxes):

        self.box[i].grid_remove()
        self.choice_title.grid_remove()
        self.frame_table.grid_columnconfigure(7, weight=0)
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "Value fixed.")
elif choice == "List":
    self.win2 = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
    self.win2.title("List")
    self.list_text = Label(self.win2, text="Please enter number of values to be used:")
    self.list_text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    self.value = StringVar()
    self.list_values = Entry(self.win2, textvariable=self.value, justify="center")
    self.list_values.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

    list_button = ttk.Button(self.win2, text="Enter", command=self.ValueBox)
    list_button.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    self.win2.mainloop()

    column = 7
    self.number_boxes = int(self.number_boxes)
    self.numbers = [StringVar() for i in xrange(self.number_boxes) ]  
    self.box = []

    for i in xrange(self.number_boxes):
        self.clicked.append(False)
        self.choice_title = Label(self.frame_table, bg=self.mycolour, borderwidth=0, width=10) 
        self.choice_title.grid(row=1, column=self.column, columnspan=self.number_boxes, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1) 
        self.box.append(Entry(self.frame_table,bg='white',borderwidth=0, width=10, justify="center", textvariable=self.numbers[i], fg='grey'))
        self.box[i].grid(row=self.row_list,column=self.column+i, sticky='nsew', padx=1, pady=1) 
        self.box[i].insert(0, "Value %g" % float(i+1))
        self.box[i].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event : self.callback(event))

        self.total_boxes = self.number_boxes * ( rows - 2 )
        self.boxes=[]
        self.boxes.append(self.box[i])

        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "Please fill in list values.")

    for i in self.numbers: 
        i.trace('w',lambda : self.numberwritten() ) 

    elif choice == "Min" or "Max":

        self.numbers = [StringVar() for i in xrange(2) ] #Name available in global scope. 
        self.number_boxes = 2
        self.box = []
        for i in xrange(2): 
            self.clicked.append(False)
            self.choice_title = Label(self.frame_table, bg=self.mycolour, borderwidth=0)
            self.choice_title.grid(row=1, column=self.column, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            self.box.append(Entry(self.frame_table,bg='white',borderwidth=0,textvariable=self.numbers[i], justify='center', fg='grey'))
            self.box[i].grid(row=self.row_list, column=self.column+i, sticky='nsew', padx=1, pady=1) 
        if i == 0:
            self.box[0].insert(0, "Min value")
        elif i == 1:
            self.box[1].insert(0, "Max value")
            self.box[i].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event : self.callback(event))
            self.boxes=[]
            self.boxes.append(self.box[i])

        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "Enter Min/Max values.")

        for i in self.numbers: 
            i.trace('w',lambda a,b,n=i: self.numberwritten(n) )
```

UPDATE section

```
def numberwritten(self): # where the above code block is usually all indented differently in comparision to this.
    self.numbers.get()

def callback(self, event, index):

    if (self.clicked[index] == False):
        self.box[index].delete(0, END)
        self.box[index].config(fg='black')
        self.clicked[index] = True
```

I don't want to bombard this question with code but if any other functions such as numberwritten are needed I can provide them. I would very much appreciate some help as I'm nearing the end of it but am struggling with the 'final touches'.

Comment: You have at least 1 indentation error.  Could you fix that (in the first `for i in xrange(...)` )

Comment: Sorry, getting frustrated with code input. Should be all fixed now.

Comment: Code input here is a pain.  I found a few things that are fishy -- I'm writing an "answer" now.

Comment: In response to your update: As far as I can tell, `self.numbers` is a list, where I think you're expecting it to be a `StringVar`.  Also, you (probably) should return something from `numberwritten`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things fishy in the following loop (I'll add comments at the fishy spots).

```
for i in xrange(self.number_boxes):
    self.clicked.append(False)
    self.choice_title = Label(self.frame_table, bg=self.mycolour, borderwidth=0, width=10)  #Fishy
    self.choice_title.grid(row=1, column=self.column, columnspan=self.number_boxes, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1) 
    self.box.append(Entry(self.frame_table,bg='white',borderwidth=0, width=10, justify="center", textvariable=self.numbers[i], fg='grey'))
    self.box[i].grid(row=self.row_list,column=self.column+i, sticky='nsew', padx=1, pady=1) 
    self.box[i].insert(0, "Value %g" % float(i+1))
    self.box[i].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, index=i : self.callback(event, index))

    self.total_boxes = self.number_boxes * ( rows - 2 ) #fishy
    self.boxes=[] #fishy
    self.boxes.append(self.box[i])

    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "Please fill in list values.") #fishy
```

First, you're creating the `choice_title` labels, but you're only keeping a reference to one of them that you're creating.  perhaps you should change that to a list and append to it like you do with the box list.

Second, `self.total_boxes` doesn't need to be calculated every time through the loop.  It can be calculated at the end (I think).

Third, `self.boxes=[]` should be moved before the loop.  What you're doing is equivalent to:  `self.boxes=[self.box[i]]` at every step of the loop.  When you're done, you only have one box in your boxes list (the last one).

Fourth, you prompt the user with a message box at every iteration of the loop.  Is that really what you want?  Or is it an indentation error?

There may be more stuff here that is a little weird, but these give you a place to start.  Here's how I think it should look:

```
self.box=[]
self.boxes=[]
self.choice_title=[]
for i in xrange(self.number_boxes):
    self.clicked.append(False)
    choice_title = Label(self.frame_table, bg=self.mycolour, borderwidth=0, width=10)  #Fishy
    choice_title.grid(row=1, column=self.column, columnspan=self.number_boxes, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    self.choice_title.append(choice_title)
    box=Entry(self.frame_table,bg='white',borderwidth=0, width=10, justify="center", textvariable=self.numbers[i], fg='grey')
    self.box.append(box)
    box.grid(row=self.row_list,column=self.column+i, sticky='nsew', padx=1, pady=1) 
    box.insert(0, "Value %g" % float(i+1))
    box.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, index=i : self.callback(event, index))

    self.boxes.append(box)  #This is still a little weird since self.box and self.boxes are essentially the same information.

self.total_boxes = self.number_boxes * ( rows - 2 ) #fishy
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "Please fill in list values.")
```

Comment: Thank you. Would it make sense to just have the list boxes then?

Comment: I've done that and it works and had to change the 'self' stuff around a bit to be able to remove them (in what you've seen in my previous question). How would I be able to update getting each input value back? I've started to try and look at it, I'll update if I manage to get there before you...!

Comment: to get the data in the i'th box, you'd do `self.boxes[i].get()` or I guess `self.numbers[i].get()`

Comment: And yes, it makes complete sense to just have the list `boxes` instead of `box` and `boxes`.

Comment: I've added in the definitions I'm currently attempting to use when getting the values back but am not completely confused and lost..